# Use child class for property in an interface implementation

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, interface, subclass

Given a class

```
public class MovementType
    Public Sub Move()
        //Move around
    End Sub
End class
```

and an interface

```
public Interface IMovingObject
    Property mType As MovementType
    Sub Move()
End Interface
```

I would like to have several implementations of this Interface for different subclasses of MovementType. For example I would like to have an implementation of IMovingObject for each of the following subclasses where i set mType to an instance of these classes.

```
public class Swimming
    Inherits MovementType

    public Sub dive()
        //breathe
        //dive
    End Sub
End class
```

or

```
public class Flying
    Inherits MovementType

    public Sub land()
        //catch CanNotLandOnLavaException
    End Sub
End class
```

Thus i would like to create something like this:

```
public class FlyingObject
    Implements IMovingObject

    Property mType As Flying
    public Sub Move()
        mType.Move()
    End Sub
End class
```

The reason why I want a setup like this is that i want to be able to manage FlyingObjects and SwimmingObjects with the same interface to move them around. However in some cases i need to call specific Methods (like mType.dive() for a SwimmingObject) when i have a concrete implementation of IMovingObject. Thus it is mandatory for mType being "Swimming" for a SwimmingObject instead of being a generic MovementType.

The problem which i am encountering in my example is of course that FlyingObject does not implement IMovingObject because mType does not have the Type "MovementType" which is specified in the Interface.

A possible solution would be setting mType to an instance of "Flying"

```
public class FlyingObject
    Implements IMovingObject

    Property mType As MovementType

    Public Sub New()
        mType = New Flying()
    End Sub

    public Sub Move()
        mType.Move()
    End Sub
End class
```

Then i could call the land() method from anywhere by using

```
Ctype(mtype,Flying).land()
```

Using direct casts all over the place does not seem like a viable solution though. What would be the "correct" way to implement this?

Please note that the above code is just an example and ignore unusual naming conventions and the fact that it does not make sense to give a type the ability to "dive" or "land". I just wanted to give you some code to work with here :)

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you want

```
Public Interface IMover(Of Out TMovementType As MovementType)
    Property MovementType As TMovementType
    Sub Move()
End Interface
```

which would lead to

```
Public class FlyingObject
    Implements IMover<Flying>

    Property MovementType As Flying

    Public Sub Move()
        Me.MovementType.Move()
    End Sub
End Class
```